# changing html text and back again with javascrip

Tags: javascript, html

How to change text with my function and also to get the same initial text back with that same function by clicking on a button?

Below is my HTML code:

```
<h1 id="change">Hello</h1>
<button onclick ="myFunction()">click</button>
```

Below is my Javascript code

````
function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "just changed text";

}```
````

Comment: You need to save the original text into either a global variable or hidden html element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a variable with the text you want to use, and whenever you replace the text, save the previous text in that variable:

```js
var txt = 'just changed text';

var el = document.getElementById('change');

function myFunction() {
  var temp = el.innerText;
  el.innerText = txt;
  txt = temp;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="change">Hello</h1>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to save the original text somewhere and when the button is clicked you set the text to that saved text.

```js
const h1Tag = document.querySelector("#change");
const originalText = h1Tag.innerText;

function myFunction() {
  if (originalText === h1Tag.innerText) {
    h1Tag.innerText = "just changed text";
  } else {
    h1Tag.innerText = originalText;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="change">Hello</h1>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change</button>
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Use a ternary operator:

```js
function myFunction(){
  const ch = document.getElementById("change")
  ch.innerHTML = ch.innerHTML === "Hello" ? "just changed text" : "Hello"
}
```

```html
<h1 id="change">Hello</h1>
<button onclick ="myFunction()">click</button>
```

To cycle through an endless array of text options:

```js
const arr = ["just changed text", "Hello", "Third option", "Fourth option"]

function myFunction(){
  const ch = document.getElementById("change")
  let idx =  arr.indexOf(ch.innerHTML)
  ch.innerHTML = arr[(idx + 1) % arr.length]
}
```

```html
<h1 id="change">Hello</h1>
<button onclick ="myFunction()">click</button>
```

Comment: If you want to cycle an array of values assign the current viewable item's index to a variable (`current`). Get the next index by adding one to the current. Since you want to cycle the array use `current = (current + 1) % arr.length`.